# loading javascript through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am fairly new to AJAX

I have a webpage (say webpage A) which upon a certain button press, calls webpage B through AJAX. webpage B is having 2 javascript files included. Now whenever I click the button, the javascript files are not being loaded. its correspoing CSS files are loaded successfully by AJAX. Here is what I got after inspection-

[image: error is on line 7372 in jquery.js]

Here arise my question 1- how is it making call to wdm.js? = *some random number* ??

Now, for the workaround, I have tried to load the javascript files by using `jQuery.getScript()` function using this code-

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST", url: "webpageB.php", data: "id="+id,
         complete: function(data){
                           //some code

                           $.getScript('js/wdm.js');

                           // some code
                }
           });
```

still I am getting this error now-

Now my question 2 arises here- Why is that the random number, came out of nowhere, is appearing into ajax GET request?

I can not use the javascript on webpage A for some reasons, So the only option left is to load the javascripts dynamically (synchronously with DOM elements of webpage B). Can anyone suggest some method?

[image: url still have that random number]

Edited- using the function `ajaxsetup` do remove the random number appearing in the URL, but now I see the file is still not being loaded by ajax, even though chrome inspector(which I use to monitor the ajax calls) do not show any errors. Now the situation is bit complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random number is timestamp which is used to prevent browser's cache. If that's not what you want, add `cache : true` option in ajax call. For example: `$.ajax({url: "url", success: callback, cache: true});`. If you want to prevent all future AJAX requests from being cached by default(this is actually the default setting in jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is that the random number, came out of nowhere, is appearing into ajax GET request?

This random number, applied in such a manner, is utterly useless in its content. It is used for cache busting. Basically, having that query string attached to the file reference will ensure that a cached version of the file is never used.